# Can Django changes model instance status when transaction.atomic rolled back?

Tags: python, django, transactions

I want order changes status when raising exception in transaction.atomic block.

Does the following code work?

```py
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        order = Order.objects.create(
            status='PAYING'
        )
except Exception as e:
    order.status = 'FALIED'
    order.save()
```

Comment: If an exception is raised, likely `order` hasn't been created, so you can't set its status to anything…

Comment: There's also no reason to assume that if the first save fails the second should work, but that's probably because this example is reduced too much to the basics.

Answer (score 1):

As written that won't work, since `create()` raises an exception before it can return a value for `order`.

Note, though, that [`create()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#create) is just shorthand for creating an instance and saving it. So you can write it this way instead:

```
order = Order(status='PAYING')
try:
    with transaction.atomic():
        order.save()
except Exception as e:
    order.status = 'FALIED'
    order.save()
```